Can't add Active Directory domain users to local groups intermittently
Active Directory domain on one Windows Server 2019 domain controller (DC). 120 Windows endpoints on the domain that use only the DC IP address as their one and  only DNS server. Half are Surface Laptop Gos, half are Lenovo Yogas running Windows 11 and a few Windows 10.
The error below occurs on both kinds of computers and both operating systems.
When joining a computer using the wizard a  domain administrator account credentials, the process also adds the domain join account to the local Administrators group.
One in 10 times, the add user wizard will say "there was a problem," and I click 'skip' on the add user wizard. The domain join is successful, but the domain join account is not added to the Administrators group.
Sometimes disconnecting  the network and reconnecting works, but most of the time it will not, this time saying, "there was an error."
This is an intermittent problem. It does not occur on most computers, and does not occur consistently on the same computer.
When the issue occurs, and I put the computer away for a bit then come back and try to add the domain user again, usually it will work, but occasionally it still won't.
Event viewer shows "Event 12, AppModel-State" occurring at the time. The message is "Failure to write an application setting for package Microsoft.Surfacehub.... Error code -2147023878."
I can't confirm this event is connected to the failed addition of the user.
What is going on, and how can I prevent this?
Alternately: What logs can I look at to find more information about what's causing this error?
UPDATE:
When I use the command line method of adding the user:
net localgroup Administrators /add domain\username

Which I got from this stack overflow question this error occurs:
The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
From This question I tried the solution of resetting the trust relationship:
Reset-ComputerMachinePassword -Server DomainControllerNameOrIP -Credential Domain\AdminAccountName

However, it did not fix the trust relationship.

Why exactly are you explicitly adding the domain administrator account to the computer?
Domain membership automatically implies that all domain administrators have administrative rights on all domain computers (i.e. the Domain Admins Active Directory group is automatically added to the local Administrators group upon joining the domain).

You have one DC, and one IP address for all domain records, and the endpoints only use that one IP address for their DNS?

@Massimo thank you, but I also want to add other administrative accounts to that computer, so I still have the question.

@GregAskew Yes. I have one Domain Controller and all the endpoints use that IP address.

@Massimo When I try to log in as administrator I also get the message that the trust relationship has failed. This seems to be the core problem and I can't fix that. I'm not sure if I should put this in a new question.

This sounds easily reproducible, so you may want to try a test. Enable netlogon debug logging on the endpoint, and reproduce the symptom.Netlogon-related activity is logged to %windir%\debug\netlogon.log. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/windows-security/enable-debug-logging-netlogon-service

The problem is the machines have lost the trust relationship with the domain controller. Experience has shown me that this seems to happen when they are behind enough on security updates.
Frustratingly, doing the security updates while they're connected to the domain don't seem to work. What has worked is disconnecting them from the domain, doing the updates, then reconnecting them to the domain. At that point the trust relationship is restored and I can add the domain users. I don't know if this is always the solution to this problem, but it's worked enough that I'm going to list it as solved.

This sounds like the system clocks may be out of sync. Ensure the client's system clock is in sync with the domain controller before attempting to join the domain or do any domain operations, as if it's more than 5 minutes off (by default settings), authentication will not succeed and any number of varying problems can result.
Also ensure that your time zones are accounted for when checking the clocks - 5:00PM EST is 2:00PM PST, not 5:00PM PST, and so on.
The intermittent nature of the problem, and the problem sometimes fixing itself, are also consistent with time sync issues, as network time can sync up the clocks later and suddenly things start working with no changes made by you.
